# When implementing Branch For Release in Trunk Based Development how should version info be updated?

Tags: git

I am currently implementing a [Trunk Based Development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) workflow utilizing [Short Lived Feature Branches](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/short-lived-feature-branches/) in a project I am working on. Recently I have realized my release strategy is less than optimal, and I'm working to move to a [Branch For Release](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/), strategy for creating new releases.

Given I am implementing Branch For Release, how should my version update commit be done? My inclination is that I create a release branch off of trunk, and the first commit to that release branch is the version update commit. Is this correct? Should a version update commit ever be done on trunk and possibly cherry-picked in?

If I'm doing things this way, where would my CI/CD pipeline look for the last version released in order to auto update the semantic version for the next release? Is there a standard place the version information is pulled from, or is it gleamed from the git graph itself (looking at let's say a git tag or something)?

In general, I'm just trying to really understand where this release specific information (build number is another component of this type of info) is committed / stored / retrieved from in a trunk based development branch for release workflow.

Thanks for any help in advance!

[image: Sample Graph With Release]

Comment: See also: [Low maintenance approach to handling versioning and git](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/442220/118878).

Comment: In general, have a look at [questions tagged `git` and `versioning`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git+versioning) for lots of additional information.

Comment: I would recommend against trying to use git as way of controlling your software release versions entirely (i.e. simply don't store "real" versions in git -- at best you may wish to use "tags" as a way of linking a commit to a released version stored somewhere else, but I would not treat git as the controller or source of your versions).   Instead consider deferring any kind of release versioning as a "packaging" step to happen after a successful build,  storing complete, built, deployable, versioned artefacts in some kind of artefact registry (which are better suited to versioning).

Comment: To expand on @BenCottrell's comment, you also don't want to store information in Git about what is deployed to which environment. [This is not a problem version control was meant to solve](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/438417).

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74552819/when-implementing-branch-for-release-in-trunk-based-development-how-should-versi "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great answers! I definititely understand that cross-posting is frowned upon, but I wasn't sure what to do with the fact that I was on the fence when posting my question as to which community it would be more appropriate for. After posting in stack-overflow and getting no answers, I tried here. I am curious how that situation should be handled in future .

Comment: Two options come to mind. Each community has a meta site (e.g. [meta]) where you could ask if the question is a good fit. Failing that, just decide on one community and post there first. If you decide to post the same question on another stack, delete the original so that the question only exists on one site.

Comment: Thanks Greg, really appreciate the insight :). That's exactly what I ended up doing .